# string replacement in python

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

I have a string of the form:

```
"77.1234 15.3456,79.8765 15.6789,81.9876 16.0011"
```

I need to convert it to the form:

```
[[77.1234,15.3456],[79.8765,15.6789],[81.9876,16.0011]]
```

Can someone help me to accomplish this using the replace() function in python? If it cannot be achieved with that, then what other function provided by python can be used?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use list comprehension,

First split the string by comma, then split each element of the new list by space and cast it into a float type.

```
>>> x = "77.1234 15.3456,79.8765 15.6789,81.9876 16.0011"
>>> [[float(j) for j in i.split()] for i in x.split(',')]
[[77.1234, 15.3456], [79.8765, 15.6789], [81.9876, 16.0011]]
```

It achieves the same result as this:

```
>>> x = "77.1234 15.3456,79.8765 15.6789,81.9876 16.0011"
>>> ls = []
>>> for i in x.split(','):
...     for j in i.split():
...             ls.append(float(j))
... 
>>> ls
[77.1234, 15.3456, 79.8765, 15.6789, 81.9876, 16.0011]
```

Answer (score 6):

Use a list comprehension with [`map`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#map):

```
>>> s = "77.1234 15.3456,79.8765 15.6789,81.9876 16.0011"
>>> [list(map(float, x.split())) for x in s.split(',')]
[[77.1234, 15.3456], [79.8765, 15.6789], [81.9876, 16.0011]]
```

In Python 2 you can remove the `list()` call around map.

Answer (score 2):

`replace` will not convert strings to floating point numbers. You need to call `float` to do that.

One option would be:

```
In [1]: s = "77.1234 15.3456,79.8765 15.6789,81.9876 16.0011"

In [2]: [[float(n) for n in p.split()] for p in s.split(',')]
Out[2]: [[77.1234, 15.3456], [79.8765, 15.6789], [81.9876, 16.0011]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> [map(float, x.split()) for x in s.split(',')]
[[77.1234, 15.3456], [79.8765, 15.6789], [81.9876, 16.0011]]
```